# Switching user in Fabric using with settings(user='user')

Tags: python, fabric

I'm trying to switch user in Fabric:

```
def check_user():
    with settings(user='linevich'):
        run("whoami")
```

Result:

```
[root@127.0.0.1:10022] Executing task 'check_user'
[root@127.0.0.1:10022] run: whoami
[root@127.0.0.1:10022] Login password for 'linevich': 
[root@127.0.0.1:10022] out: root
```

What's wrong?
(No, I don't want to use `sudo()` instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
I used following command to launch script:

```
fab -H root@127.0.0.1:10022
```

Right way - run it **without setting username**:

```
fab -H 127.0.0.1:10022
```